# Postgresql fetch raw value in two tables which have in same column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following two tables

```
Table_one

school_id subjec_code   student_count
0001      S1            25
0001      S2            10
0002      S1            38
0002      S2            12

Table_two

school_id subject_code techer_count
0001      S2           2
0001      S1           3
0002      S1           1
0002      S2           2


Result I want is 

school_id subject student_count teacher_count
0001      s1      25            3
0001      s2      10            2
0002      s1      38            1
```

I have tried to join this two tables with supporting school_id and subject_code, but I could't get relevant count for each subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure there will be records for all school/sub code in both tables, you can remove the FULL OUTER portion.

```
SELECT Table_one.school_id, Table_one.subjec_code as subject, Table_one.student_count,
     Table_two.subjec_code, Table_two.teacher_count
    FROM Table_one FULL OUTER JOIN  Table_two
    ON Table_one.school_id = Table_two.school_id
    AND Table_one.subjec_code = Table_two.subjec_code
    ORDER BY table_one.school_id, Table_one.subjec_code;
```

You have subjec_code in one table and subject_code in the other. I have used subjec_code in both.

Comment: Yep i got your code, i have done this while your posting this answer. But this is good one when comparing my code . Again thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query this will solve your problem

```
SELECT Table_one.school_id, Table_one.subject_code as subject, Table_one.student_count,
     Table_two.subject_code, Table_two.teacher_count
    FROM Table_one, Table_two
    WHERE Table_one.school_id = Table_two.school_id;
```

Comment: it gives me a empty result :(

Comment: Ok i got the result but , its doesnt shows the relevant result, it will be ok table_two has same subject order as in table_one

Comment: you can use order if both table has not same subject order.

Comment: result according to you
'
school_id subject student_count subject_teacher teacher_count
0001      s1      25            s2                3
0001      s2      10            s1                2
0002      s1      38            s1                1

'

Comment: you can use order by table_two.teacher_count desc if you want get result no. of teacher in decreasing order